# MVC 3, After Insert, Before Update, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

tell me please, how i can do "triggers" or "callbacks" for Models in asp.net mvc3?
For example, i have 3 models in db

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string order_num { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; private set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int sheets_num { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int orderID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("orderID")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int spoolID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("spoolID")]
    public virtual Spool Spool { get; set; }
}

public class Spool
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public int weight_meter { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

In program i create order - it has many tasks. When i create task - it should change weight of spool

```
Task.Spool.Weight = Task.Spool.Weight - (Task.length * Task.sheets_num * Task.Spool.weight_meter)
```

when i delete order - it should delete all tasks and change weight of spool and etc. for update ( spool.weight = spool.weight + WeightOfOldTask - WeightOfNewTask)

How i can do this things in asp? In rails i can use callbacks in model (after_update and others)

Answer (score 1):

This not really something that is built into MVC, it is more like what would be built into an ORM that you used to map your models to the database line Entity Framework or LinqToSQL.

If you want to do this without an ORM framework you would have to write the code for this yourself. Either way it would probably use net [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and then trigger them in the getters and setters of your model.